# How do I get dimensions for an object?

Tags: mesh

This is an object for which I want dimensions. [image: 3D printed components]

Comment: Click the tiny + sign(top right in that view) or press n to open the transform properties. After the Location, Rotation and Scale details is Dimensions. Just make sure Scale is all 1 or apply Scale Ctrl+A

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, you can have the object's dimensions in the side bar. But understand it's only the objects panel from a bounding box. In your case, the dimensions are calculated from a box kind of like this :
[image]

If you want more precise measurements, ex something like that:
[image]

You can use the [MeasureIt addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0jCdCoaRvs). AFAIK it's included in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the little + sign on the right side of the 3d viewport, it will bring up a bar. You can also press N to bring it up. You can see the dimensions in the top of that panel. It is labeled with "Dimensions"

I don't have the score to make a comment, but I wanted to include in @rob's comment that the information is at the top and below the position information.